# UPDATED WITH FIX: Is there a way to loop an object and save/update a mongodb document on each iteration without getting ParallelSaveError?

Tags: mongodb, loops, object, mongoose

I want to update the mongodb document on every loop but seems not to work. I used map to loop through the object and was getting a

> parallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel

So now using async.each to loop through the object but seems mongoose only save once. Code below

```
const openTrade = await TradeModel.find({
  $and: [{ isOpen: true }, { price: { $lte: price } }]
})
  .sort("volume")
  .where({ userId: { $ne: req.authUser._id } });
trade = async openTrade => {
  const buyerInfo = await UserModel.findById(req.authUser._id);
  const buyerWallet = await WalletModel.findById(buyerInfo.walletId);
  const sellerInfo = await UserModel.findById(openTrade.userId);
  const sellerWallet = await WalletModel.findById(sellerInfo.walletId);

  buyerWallet.balance = parseInt(buyerWallet.balance) - amountToPay;
  sellerWallet.balance = parseInt(sellerWallet.balance) + amountToPay;
  await Promise.all([sellerWallet.save(), buyerWallet.save()]);
};
async.forEachOf(openTrade, trade);
```

So I finally found the issue. I did not make the buyerInfo, sellerInfo and Wallets variable constant. So now it works. Thanks

Comment: Try removing "_id" from sellerWallet and buyerWallet objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below: As according to MongoDB [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/#update)  If the document contains an _id field, then the save() method is equivalent to an update with the upsert option set to true and the query predicate on the _id field.

```
const openTrade = await TradeModel.find({$and:[{isOpen : true}, {price : {$lte : price}}]}).sort('volume').where({userId : {$ne : req.authUser._id } })
            trade = async (openTrade)=>{
            buyerInfo = await UserModel.findById(req.authUser._id)
            buyerWallet = await WalletModel.findById(buyerInfo.walletId)
            sellerInfo = await UserModel.findById(openTrade.userId)
            sellerWallet = await WalletModel.findById(sellerInfo.walletId)
            delete buyerWallet._id;
            delete sellerWallet._id;
            buyerWallet.balance = parseInt(buyerWallet.balance) - amountToPay
            sellerWallet.balance = parseInt(sellerWallet.balance) + amountToPay  
           await Promise.all([sellerWallet.save(), buyerWallet.save()])

        }
        async.forEachOf(openTrade, trade)
```

Comment: If the document contains an _id field, save is equivalent to update then why delete _id. Also, I noticed delete buyerWallet._id does not work until I convert to toObject() which does not update the document after that.